# Setup a wireless home network with wireless internet access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

My apartment building provides free wireless network connection to the internet, included with the rent. The wlan has no password protection.

I would like to setup a wireless router in a way it uses the apartment building's wlan as the route to the Internet, but the wireless router would also create another, a private wlan for me to use within my apartment.

I am paying for a secure VPN connection to ensure some privacy for my internet connection. So I would like to setup the router to route all traffic to the VPN so I wouldn't need to setup the VPN to every device I want to use.

I currently own Buffalo AirStation WHR-G300N and Asus RT-10+ wireless routers. Can I use these to build this kind of setup or do I need something else?

Comment: This entire depends on if your router support can be configured to connect to a VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with routers running special software, called *DD-WRT*, or *OpenWRT*. They are both excellent, with *OpenWRT* being, IMHO, less suited to novices.

The configuration you are searching for is the [Client Mode Wireless](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless), not to be confused with a wireless bridge. The *Client Mode Wireless* does exactly what you are asking for, *i.e.*, it connects as a client to your house's wifi network, but acts as a router, *i.e.* it creates a LAN-side subnet which differs from the WAN-side network, and separates them so that people on the WAN side of your router cannot access components on its LAN-side.

Also, *DD-WRT* and *OpenWRT* can be easily configured to act as VPN clients (or servers!) and to route all the traffic from their LAN-side through the VPN, increasing the privacy and the security of its clients.

Many routers sold commercially can be **flashed** (the technical term for *endowed with*) *DD-WRT* and *OpenWRT*; you can easily find via Google which routers are suitable for this operation. However, you may also wish to consider Buffalo routers, some of which come with *DD-WRT* conveniently pre-installed.